# File upload in struts2 using s:file

Tags: jsp, file-upload, struts2

I am trying to upload the file using S:file tag but it is giving me http 500 internal error. But When I directly give filename and path as constant in same code it works. So I am not sure where I am missing the loop hole.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Struts 2 - Login Application | ViralPatel.net</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Struts 2 - Login Application</h2>
<s:actionerror  />
<s:form action="uploadFile.action"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<s:textfield name="myName"></s:textfield>
  <s:file name="myFile"></s:file>
    <s:submit  value="Submit" align="center" />
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Action

```
class FileUploadAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware {
    File userImage;
    String userImageContentType;
    String userImageFileName;
    HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    public String execute() {
        try {
            String filePath = servletRequest.getSession()
                    .getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
            File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.userImageFileName);
            FileUtils.copyFile(this.userImage, fileToCreate);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            addActionError(e.getMessage());
            return INPUT;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
        servletRequest = servletRequest;
    }
}
```

Config

```
<action name="userImage" class="net.viralpatel.struts2.FileUploadAction"> 
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"> 
        <param name="maximumSize">2097152</param> 
        <param name="allowedTypes">
                  image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg
            </param> 
    </interceptor-ref> 
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
    </interceptor-ref> 
    <result name="success">SuccessUserImage.jsp</result> 
    <result name="input">UserImage.jsp</result> 
</action>
```

---

EDIT: next time edit your post instead of posting code in comments...

Comment: Please post your `UploadFile` action.

Comment: What exception do you get?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: 
your Action does not have a `private File myFile;` with its GETTER.

Start correcting that...

---

The problem is probably in your Action code, not here.

What do you mean that it works if you pass Strings containing file name / path ?

Do you have a `private File myFile;` with public accessors (getters and setters) in the Action (and File is java.io.File, not some other File) ?

Take a look at this two simple tutorials too:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts-2-file-upload-save-tutorial-with-example/

http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/struts-2-file-upload.shtml

Comment: This is probably more comment than an answer.

Comment: Yeah but quite long for a comment :/

Comment: When I use enctype="multipart/form-data" in my jsp file then I get HTTP 500 internal error and when I do not use it, I get HTTP 404 not found exception.

Comment: If I pass file string through text box then I create File object like File myFile=new File(fileName); In this case I am able to upload file. I am using Viralpatel's blog code only. Same code is giving error.

Comment: Yeah, i wrote the answer because i thought that your alternate solution was to pass string and instantiate File, that is obviously totally another thing. Please post your Action code and your Struts.xml config, so we can help you find the bug...

Comment: class FileUploadAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware {
File userImage;
String userImageContentType;
String userImageFileName;
HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
public String execute(){
try {
String filePath = servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.userImageFileName);
FileUtils.copyFile(this.userImage, fileToCreate);
}catch (Exception e) {addActionError(e.getMessage());return INPUT;}return SUCCESS;}
public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
servletRequest = servletRequest;
}
}

Comment: I removed some key words and format bcoz code was crossing the max char limit in the comment...

Comment: here is struts.xml

<action name="userImage"
    class="net.viralpatel.struts2.FileUploadAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="maximumSize">2097152</param>
        <param name="allowedTypes">
            image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg
        </param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
    <result name="success">SuccessUserImage.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">UserImage.jsp</result>
</action>

Comment: @user1917911: Edit your question, do not put code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting `fileUpload` interceptor twice to your action interceptor stack because the `defaultStack` already includes `fileUpload` interceptor. You can configure interceptors inside stack like that:

```
<action ...>
  <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
    <param name="fileUpload.allowedTypes">
      image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg
    </param>
  </interceptor-ref>
  <result ... />
</action>
```

Also make sure you have public getters/setters for your variables inside action class.